# How to make a form wait for ajax to finish before it submits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preventdefault

So there is a form that i want to submit only when a condition is verified from the database using ajax. I am using `preventDefault()` method if the condition is true i.e. if a user is not a resident, a variable is set to true in `ajax successs function` and `preventDefault()` gets called, however, when doing this, the form always submits. It doesn't wait for the ajax to finish even when async is set to false.
Here's the code.

```
  $('#button').click(function(e) {    
    if ($('#ca_resident').prop('checked') == true) { 
      amount=$('#user-amount').val().replace(/[,]/g,"");
      project_name=$('#project_name').val();
      var not_resident = false;
       $.ajax({
        url: '/main/verify_residence/',
        type: 'POST',
        aysnc: false,
        data: {
          value: amount,
          name: project_name
        },
        success: function(data){
          $("#verify_residence").html(data);
          not_resident = true;
        },
        dataType: 'html'
      }); 
    }
    if(not_resident){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

Comment: prevent the default before calling the ajax and on `ajax.success` you can then `form.submit()`

Comment: Try return false; instead of e.preventDeafult().

Comment: @Vogel612 I tried doing that before. this prevents form from submitting in any condition. The form should submit when a user doesn't fail residency check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that won't work. Success will fire **after**:

```
if(not_resident){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

As it's asynchronous. You need to always cancel the button click then submit the form once success is hit:

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {    
   var $form = $(this).closest('form');   

   if ($('#ca_resident').prop('checked') == true) { 
      amount=$('#user-amount').val().replace(/[,]/g,"");
      project_name=$('#project_name').val();
       $.ajax({
        url: '/main/verify_residence/',
        type: 'POST',
        aysnc: false,
        data: {
          value: amount,
          name: project_name
        },
        success: function(data){
          $("#verify_residence").html(data);
          $form.submit();
        },
        dataType: 'html'
      }); 
    }


    e.preventDefault();

  });
```

Comment: thanks Liam, but what i need is if a user fails residence condition the form doesn't submit, exactly opposite. `e.preventDefault()` in the `success function`. still no luck

Comment: @user2488801 this will do that, if the `success` isn't hit. the form will not submit. `e.preventDefault();` stops the form always submitting. `$form.submit();` only posts when `success` is hit

Comment: `success` is a case when a user fails validation and is not allowed to see further, i.e. no form submission.

Comment: So success is actually failure?! interesting. So what happens when it actually succeeds?

Comment: A div shows up with "Sorry you can't register" message and then the form should stop submission